# Getting a validating error of password which is not present in the edit profile page. Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to update users attributes without password in devise. The case is, when i hit update profile after editing the profile, I am getting a validating error of password which is not present in the edit profile page ! How could I do this with devise?

models/user.rb

```
validates :password, presence:true, :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
     :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }
```

My application controller is,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_paramters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_paramters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :fullname 
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :fullname << :phone_number << :description << :email << :password << :gender << :current_password << :avatar
    end
end
```

My registrationscontroller is,

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected
        def update_resource(resource, params)
            resource.update_without_password(params)
        end
end
```

My edit.html/registrations is,

```
<div class="row">
            <label class="col-xs-4" for="fullname">Fullname</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <%= f.text_field :fullname, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "Full Name", :class => 'form-control' %>
              </div>
          </div></br></br>
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-xs-4" for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
              <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, order: [:day, :month, :year], :start_year=>1910 %>
              </div>
          </div>
           <div class="row">
            <label class="col-xs-4" for="gender">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
              <%= f.check_box :gender, {}, false %> <%= f.label :gender, "Female" %>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
              <%= f.check_box :gender, {}, true %> <%= f.label :gender, "Male" %>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

My routes.rb is,

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for  :users, 
              :path => '', 
              :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
              :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}

  resources :users 

end
```

When i hit update profile then it is showing,
"Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric."

the password field is not present in the edit registrations form as i want to update without password.

Comment: did that `on: :update` helped ?

Comment: It helped but for new registrations, password is accepting even 1 character

Comment: I got it by adding validates :password, length: { in: 8..16 }, on: :create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip a validation in update, Just give option `on: :update`. This should allow to update without password required. lmk...

```
  validates :password, length: { in: 8..16 }, on: :create
  validates :password, length: { in: 8..16 }, on: :update, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to tell Devise to use your controller instead. Update your routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Comment: Hmm... Then, the only problem that I can think of, is that you created the user you are trying to update before you added model validations. So, now AR is not letting your update your existing user with a password that is less than 6 symbols and does not have lowercase and uppercase letters. Update that user's password to a valid one.

Comment: Sorry, I have created a new user and tried to update ... still the same error